# update-alternatives returns invalid option when installing java

Tags: debian, java

I am trying to install `java` on a `debian jessie 8.8`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/local/PeykAsa/jdk1.7.0/bin/java 315
```

I get:

```
update-alternatives: unknown option `--install /usr/bin/java'
Use 'update-alternatives --help' for program usage information.
```

I don't think the command is missing something, as [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) and `man update-alternatives` says so:

```
   --install link name path priority [--slave link name path]...
          Add  a  group  of  alternatives  to  the system.  link is the generic name for the master link, name is the name of its symlink in the alternatives directory, and path is the alternative being
          introduced for the master link.  The arguments after --slave are the generic name, symlink name in the alternatives directory and the alternative path for a slave link.  Zero or  more  --slave
          options,  each followed by three arguments, may be specified. Note that the master alternative must exist or the call will fail. However if a slave alternative doesn't exist, the corresponding
          slave alternative link will simply not be installed (a warning will still be displayed). If some real file is installed where an alternative link has to be installed, it is kept unless --force
          is used.

          If  the  alternative  name  specified  exists already in the alternatives system's records, the information supplied will be added as a new set of alternatives for the group.  Otherwise, a new
          group, set to automatic mode, will be added with this information.  If the group is in automatic mode, and the newly added alternatives' priority is higher than any  other  installed  alterna‐
          tives for this group, the symlinks will be updated to point to the newly added alternatives.
```

I tried `--force`, got the same output. I have never faced such issue on `debian`, on any versions (e.g. 7, 6, 8.2, 8.8, etc.).

Comment: Are you sure that’s a standard space between `--install` and `/usr/bin/java`? It looks like it could be a non-breaking space instead.

Comment: @StephenKitt that's what it was, following from [the comment here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050079/update-alternatives-returns-invalid-option-when-installing-java?noredirect=1#comment1714575_1050079).

Comment: @StephenKitt, you are right. I asked it first in ubuntu forum (my mistake). This question was moved from there. muru answered it there and also here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you copy-pasted the command from somewhere, you probably got a Unicode character instead of an ASCII one (em-dash instead of `-`, or non-breaking space instead of space, etc.). If it were an em-dash or similar, however, it wouldn't be seen as an option argument (instead it's seen as an unrecognized option). Since `--install /usr/bin/java` is presented as one argument in the error, the space in between is probably not an ASCII space, but [a Unicode one](https://www.brunildo.org/test/space-chars.html).

Comment: Thank you my saviour. Who knew a `-` was such a headache